# Set an alert / notification with "1 line" in Google Calendar

Tags: google-calendar, notifications

In Google Calendar you can set a time for an event with 1 line by doing the following (see also screenshot below): "dinner 1pm" this will set an event for called dinner at 1pm.

What I'd also like to be able to do is set when I get the reminder for this, so: "dinner 1pm alert 45 mins".

Is something like that possible?

[image: Quick Add menu]

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK it's not possible. Instead use the set reminder feature of Google Keep or Google Inbox by Gmail.

- [Reminders - Inbox by Gmail Help](https://support.google.com/inbox/answer/6062813?hl=en)
- [Set a time reminder - Keep Help](https://support.google.com/keep/answer/3187168?hl=en)